# Read the second largest number in an array

Tags: c#, arrays

I've written a console application (.NET 5.0) in C# in Visual Studio which sorts an array from high to low and then it has to print out the second largest element in that array.

Im getting close but ive been trying things for the past 2 hours and I don't get why I always get an out of bounds error at the last 'if'. The program is supposed to detect duplicates so for instance if the input is '1 1 2 2 5 5 9 9" it will print out "5" as it is the second largest.

My current code is below I can't get it to work without crashing

using System;

```
namespace second_largest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double[] input = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(" "), Convert.ToDouble);

            for (int repeat = 0; repeat < input.Length; repeat++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < input.Length - 1; j++)
                {
                    if(input[j] < input[j+1])
                    {
                        double temp = input[j];
                        input[j] = input[j + 1];
                        input[j + 1] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
            {
                if(input[i] == input[i + 1])
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(input[i]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine(input[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/code/3108/find-the-second-highest-value-in-an-array-using-c-sharp.aspx

A good example how to do it

Comment: `if(input[i] == input[i + 1])` here `i + 1`th index is out of range since you have  `for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see the error because you iterate up to `i < input.Length` which means that `i + 1` on the following if statement is out of bounds of the length of the input array. You need to do the same thing you've done on the previous nested for loop:

`for(int i = 0; i < input.Length - 1; i++)`

Comment: ah ive found a way to do it, ive added a counter wich just counts to 2 so it will print the second element. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

There is a much easier way to get the second highest using LINQ

It involves grouping by the number (to eliminate duplicates), then ordering by the grouped key descending, then skipping one and taking one

```
var secondHighest = nums.GroupBy(n => n)
                        .OrderByDescending(n => n.Key)
                        .Skip(1)
                        .First()
                        .Key;
```

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/WlFyWr

Comment: okay thanks! I'll look into it, it. Looks confusing at first glance

Comment: you get `nums`, group by its elements `n` so that you only have each element once (`UNIQUE`), then order by descending based on the keys (keys are equal to their values because you grouped them by their values; key for group `1` is `1`), then skip the first (largest) element (it is kind of removed from the query), then get the first one (thanks to `skip(1)`, the first element now is the second largest of the original array), then get the key of this element because remember keys are equal to values.